# Using backslash (\) to indicate subfolder in ios

Tags: ios, file-structure

Please bear with me while I try to explain my problem

Suppose the folder structure of my download container's Document folder is represented `/A/B/C/`, which I have obtained through the proper API's in ViewController.m. I am porting a PC C++ project to ios, where, at one point the program decodes it's input to get the name and full path of a file, for example, as `images\background.png`. Since my program automatically locates the Document folder through API's, it is supposed to create the folder structure `/A/B/C/images\background.png`. The program I am porting to ios also contains a directory creator function, which detects the locations of `/` in the pathname string, checks whether a directory by that name is already present or not (for example, it would detect `/A` as being present, but `/A/B/C/images` would be detected as absent, as images has not been created yet). The function creates all the subfolders in this tree if they do not exist already. After the directory structure has been created (`/A/B/C/images`), the program does something like this to create the file (background.png in this example):

```
.  
.  
.  
Create directory structure  
fid = fopen(`/A/B/C/images\background.png`, "wb");  // note that full path `/A/B/C/images\background.png` is automatically determined by the program by the time it reaches this point  
.  
.  
file writing code  
fclose(fid)    
.    
.
```

My problem is that after creating the folder `images`, it creates the png file as `images\background.png`, instead of creating a `background.png` inside the images folder. I have already ported this program to android NDK and it creates the png file inside the `images` folder as expected, so I can only assume that android considers `\` to indicate a subfolder while ios doesn't.

What can be done in order to get `background.png` created inside the images subfolder? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try just replacing backslashes with forward slashes?

Comment: @rengers I am trying to see if I can do that as well. I think this problem will fix itself if I am able to replace the backslash with a forward slash, but at the point where the path string becomes available to me, it comes as a const, so I cannot directly change it either. On top of that it's not an ordinary string it's a class that they have provided.